# Remove duplicate values of custom object in arraylist

Tags: android

How to remove duplicate values from `Arraylist` that have a custom object. As I have an array list of the custom object. Custom `object(POJO)` has many duplicate entries of latitude and longitude.

Comment: post your arraylist and custom POJO

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override **hashCode()** and **equals()** method in your POJO and use **LinkedHashSet** instead of ArrayList.
LinkedHashSet automatically removes all duplicate objects.
e.g.

```
java.util.LinkedHashSet<YourPojo> uniqueObjects =new java.util.LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ankit. Your solution is really helpful for me.